# How can I keep tradicional filter format for new free-jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm trying to upgrade from jqGrid v4.7 to the latest jqGrid 4.12.1 - [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork.

The problem I face is that, using server side searching, filter parameters don´t get built using the former

```json
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Name","op":"cn","data":"bob"}]}
```

style, I just get an additional `Name` parameter with `bob` value (`_search` is `true`).

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you include JavaScript code which you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you use `filterToolbar` without `stringResult: true` parameter and the problem have no relation with the upgrade of jqGrid 4.7 to free jqGrid 4.12.1. See the first part of [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) of `filterToolbar` which describes:

> When the search is activated, an array of type `name:value` is posted
>   to the server. Note that this array is added to the `postData`
>   parameter. We post only fields that have an entered value. When we
>   clear the the search form, the values are deleted from the `postData`
>   array. When posting to the server, we try to pass, not the name, but
>   the `index` set in `colModel`. When the `index` is not found we use
>   the `name`. Additionally, we add a `_search=true` to the posted data.
>
> When the `stringResult` option is set to true the data posted to the
>   server is a string and the structure of the posted data is the same as
>   in [Advanced Search](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options).